# How could the complexity of bucket sort is O(n+k)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Before saying "this has been asked before", or "find an algorithm book", please read on and tell me what part of my reasoning went wrong?

Say you have n intergers, and you divded them into k bins, this will take O(n) time. However, one need to sort each of the k bins, if using quick sort for each bin this is an O((n/k)*log(n/k)) operation, so this step would take O(n*log(n/k)+k). Finally one need to assemble this array, this takes O(n+k), (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311415/how-is-the-complexity-of-bucket-sort-is-onk-if-we-implement-buckets-using-lin)), so the total operation would be O(n+n*log(n/k)+k). Now, how did this n*log(n/k) disappeared, I could not figure at all. My guess is there is some mathematics going on which eliminates this n*log(n/k). Anyone could help?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption:

- k - the number of buckets - is arbitrary

is wrong.

There are two variants of bucket sort, so it is quite confusing.

---

**A**

The number of buckets is equal to the number of items in the input

See analysis [here](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/bucketSort.htm)

---

**B**

The number of buckets is equal to *R* - the number of possible values for the input integers

See analysis [here](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0310-002/lectures/lecture-23.html) and [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960123.html)

Comment: There are many different versions of Bucketsort (see Wikipedia). Unsure which one he is thinking of. But you are correct for the variant where one uses n buckets.

Comment: Neither A or B is what I had in mind, for B it is called pigeonhole sort according to Wikipedia. A looks to me very inefficient, each bucket has only one items in average? What I had in mind is k<<n, say n=1000, k=10.

Comment: @John Yang: A is good when the input is generated by a random process with uniform distribution. The sorting of each bucket has theta(1), therefore the entire algorithm runs in linear expected time. B is good when k<<n.

Comment: @JohnYang Can you answer my response below? In particular what does the k mean in your algorithm, e.g., that the n numbers are all in the range from 1 - k? If the number n can be from some large set and k is small and independent of n, then you don't get O(n + k). To see this, you could for example take k=2 or k=1.

Answer (score 0):

Your flaw is assuming that quicksort is used to sort the buckets. Typically this is not the case, and that's how you avoid the `(n / k) log(n / k)` terms.

Comment: But what else can you used? Some website said you could use recursive bucket, but that would take O(n+k*2) according to my analysis.

Comment: Yes, recursive bucket is standard. And `O(n + 2k)` is `O(n + k)` (right, if `f` is bounded by `C * (n + 2k)` then `f` is bounded by `2C * (n + k)` because `2C * (n + k)` bounds `C * (2n + 2k)` which bounds `C * (n + 2k)` which bounds `f` by assumption).

Comment: @yi_H, sorry I mean O(n+k^2).

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis looks good. The term Bucketsort is used for many different algorithms, so depending on which one you looked at its average runtime might be O(n + k) or not.

If I had to guess, you might have looked at a typical variant where one chooses k very large so that n/k will be a constant. In another popular variant even k >> n, so one divides into k/n buckets instead.

If you provide the algorithm in detail and the source which claims this to be in an average of O(n + k) I can revisit my answer.

Comment: n is the number of elements to sort and k is the number of buckets, you could assume the number of elements is evenly distributed, so each buckets have n/k elements. The O(n+k) is from wikipedia.

Comment: If you're referring to wikipedia, you'll see that the number of buckets they use is n in their pseudo-code. If one were to use your algorithm (which appears nowhere on wikipedia), then if one choses k=2 one gets quicksort, which is at least O(n log n) on average.